# Smooth scroll a submit button to an onpage div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to create smooth scrolling behavior to an onpage div for a submit button?

I have something along these lines

`<input type="submit" value="FREE QUOTE!" onclick="window.location.href = '#quote';">`

That goes to the div just fine, but it jumps.

For the other anchor links on the page, I'm using a smooth-scrolling jQuery script which creates smooth scrolling for them:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

That's great, as expected, for normal anchors, but the button jumps.

I could of course style a normal anchor to have the look of this button but this breaks the design completely. If I use CSS `scroll-behavior: smooth;`, then I get a smooth scroll for this button, but there doesn't seem to be great support for this beyond recent browsers.

Is there a way to get a submit button to scroll smoothly to an onpage div? I don't mind if the scrolling for the button is a separate script/process to the vanilla anchors but would just like to get some smooth scrolling into this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another event listener that targets something like a custom data attribute, eg: `data-scroll`:

```
<input type="submit" value="FREE QUOTE!" data-scroll="#quote" />
```

Here's a quick update to your JS:

```
function scrollTo($ele) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $ele.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'linear');
}

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $ele = $($(this).attr('href'));
    scrollTo($ele);
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-scroll]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $ele = $($(this).data('scroll'));
    scrollTo($ele);
});
```